# How to create Box Shadow rollover and hover css navigation?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create the effect of box-shadow/ribbon on my navigation menu using css I have a image and sample what would like to learn to create I am a beginner web developer sorta the same as this demo here http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/33211.html  if any one can help me learn would be great.

I am just after learning how to create the nav bar which is similar to this link

Comment: try this link: http://www.css3files.com/shadow/ it explains how to use box shadows

Comment: if you wanna make box-shadow and other stuff automaticallt for you then visit: 1- css3gen.com 2- css3generator.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why you don't just make a PNG with the required shadow? Alternatively create a shadow image png and background a div with it that encompasses the ribbon.

I would avoid CSS3 for this as cross-browser compatibility will be an issue for now.

---

Start with a new image, at the required padded out size, with a transparent background. Make the shadow using gradients and then save for web. Select PNG 24 and that's it really.

Comment: I don't know how to make png images I have Photoshop though but no learning videos on you tube to help

Comment: Also if possible to make box shadow css for rollover on menu? My system will not work well using css3. I have cs5

Comment: @Andy - I guess so but I tend to make a tiny shadow image that can be used throughout as opposed to making a shadow for each image. Less work overall if you ask me.